# NullPointerException when adding elements to ArrayList

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to add elements to my ArrayList called activList using:

```
activList.add(new Fiducial(iD, x, y ));
```

But I get a NullPointerException on this line when running the code:

```
int cols = 10, rows = 10;
int rectangleWidth = 100;
int rectangleHeight = 60;

// these are some helper variables which are used
// to create scalable graphical feedback
int k, l, iD;
float cursor_size = 15;
float object_size = 60;
float table_size = 760;
float scale_factor = 1;
float x, y;

ArrayList<Fiducial> activList  ;


public class Fiducial {
  public int iD;
  public float x;
  public float y;

  public Fiducial(int iD, float x, float y) {
    this.iD = iD;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}


void draw() {
  // Begin loop for columns
  for ( k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
    // Begin loop for rows
    for ( l = 0; l < rows; l++) {
      fill(255);
      stroke(0);
      rect(k*rectangleWidth, l*rectangleHeight, rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight);
    }
  }


  // This part detects the fiducial markers 
  float obj_size = object_size*scale_factor; 
  float cur_size = cursor_size*scale_factor; 

  ArrayList<TuioObject> tuioObjectList = tuioClient.getTuioObjectList();
  for (int i=0; i<tuioObjectList.size (); i++) {
    TuioObject tobj= tuioObjectList.get(i);
    stroke(0);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(tobj.getScreenX(width), tobj.getScreenY(height));
    rotate(tobj.getAngle());
    rect(-80, -40, 80, 40);
    popMatrix();
    fill(255);
    x = round(10*tobj.getX ());
    y = round(10*tobj.getY ());
    iD = tobj.getSymbolID();
    activList.add(new Fiducial(iD, x, y ));
    fiducialCoordinates ();
  }
}


void fiducialCoordinates () {
  System.out.println("x= "+ x + " y= " + y + " iD= " + iD );
  System.out.println(activList);
}
```

I did read this page: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) (so don't report it as duplicate please)

And what I understood is that I get the error because my ArrayList doesn't have any element. However, I tried to add one right after creating it, like this:

```
ArrayList<Fiducial> activList  ;
activList.add(new Fiducial(3, 4.0, 5.0 ));
```

But I get the error: "unexpected token: ( " at the line:

```
activList.add(new Fiducial(3, 4.0, 5.0 ));
```

I don't get it, I thought adding an element would prevent it to be Null but I still get an error. How should I modify this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have `ArrayList<Fiducial> activList = new ArrayList<Fiducial>();` anywhere in your code?

Comment: This line `ArrayList<Fiducial> activList;` should be `ArrayList<Fiducial> activList = new ArrayList<Fiducial>();`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384 .. same thing, different code. Actual task/code posted is mostly irrelevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never actually instantiate the `ArrayList` using `new`. No memory has been allocated for the `ArrayList`.

Fix it like this:

```
ArrayList<Fiducial> activList = new ArrayList<Fiducial>();
```

From the docs:

> Instantiation: The new keyword is a Java operator that creates the object.
>
> Initialization: The new operator is followed by a call to a
>   constructor, which initializes the new object.

[Creating Objects Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Only with primitive types (`int`, `double`, etc.) will declaring the variable as you did allocate memory for it. Objects need the `new` keyword to have memory associated with them.

Answer (score 4):

You must initialize your reference of list, like this:

```
ArrayList<Fiducial> activList  = new ArrayList<Fiducial>();
activList.add(new Fiducial(3, 4.0, 5.0 ));
```

You indicate that reference `activList` will be specify to `ArrayList` object in heap memory. You may try the *other ways* to initialize:

```
// List -> use ArrayList or LinkedList
List<Fiducial> activList  = new ArrayList<Fiducial>();
// Collection -> use List, Set or Queue realizations
Collection<Fiducial> activList  = new ArrayList<Fiducial>();
```

It will help you make your code *more bending*.

Answer (score 3):

Just instantiate it by using the **new** keyword:

```
ArrayList<Fiducial> activList  = new ArrayList<Fiducial>();
```

or in java 7, use diamond operator:

```
ArrayList<Fiducial> activList  = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

This line automatically initializes activList to null, so you need to instatiate it.

```
ArrayList<Fiducial> activList ;
```

You need to have it be:

```
List<Fiducial> activList = new ArrayList<Fudicial>();
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other two answers:

You are not getting a null pointer error because your ArrayList is empty.

You can still make a reference to an empty arrayList.

If you couldn't, how else would you initiliaze an arrayList and assign a reference to it?

You were getting the null pointer error because you never actually initialized your `ArrayList<Fiducial>` with a `new ArrayList<Fiducial>();`

So the reference is null because it wasn't actually referencing any ArrayList.